# How to user input with condition in java?

Tags: java

I want the user to enter a value until the value he enters complies with the constraints. I want to save this value when it enters a value suitable for the constraints.
This is my rule -> 0<=x<=2^31-1 . But when I enter -1 or 41564156651 it works. How can I do this. Please help me with that.

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");

        x= Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        while (x< 0   && x> (2^31)-1) { // && firstNum > (2^31)-1
            System.out.println("0<=x<=2^31-1 please obey the rule and enter a number again.");
            x= Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        }
```

Comment: ^ operator in java does [XOR](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xor-operator) operation. For your case you want to do x<0 || x>[Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: @syncit I did your answer. And I get this error ---->>>>> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1516513513513513513"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
        at Q3.main(Q3.java:35)

Comment: That number is too large to be parsed as an `int`.

Comment: The [parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) function will automatically throw an exception if your integer is out of range thus eliminating the need for you to do explicit checking.  A better approach would be to wrap the parseInt function in an try and catch block and print your error message in the catch block.Your code works for this input

Comment: (If x is an `int`, it can never be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Answer (score 0):

I love when people put homework on here. hahaha.

You have a bug in your code. you where looking for

valid values rule:

- 0 <= x <= (2^31)-1
- MIN_VAL <= x <= MAX_VAL

invalid values rule:

- x < MIN_VAL or MAX_VAL < x

what you did:

- x < MIN_VAL **and** MAX_VAL < x

truth table

| value | x < MIN_VAL (A) | MAX_VAL < x (B) | A && B | A || B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | true | false | false | true |
| 10 | false | false | false | false |
| MAX + 1 | false | true | false | true |

As you can see, your logic can never come back as true.